# Add data with conditional INNER JOIN, but add conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dfs, one called original:

```
original
company_name  |  description | address 
---------------------------------------
```

Another called second:

```
second
company_name  |  description | address | services
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to add `services` from second to original where `company_name` is equal. I normally work with SQL, so this is a simple INNER JOIN w/ conditional. However, I want to add some boolean logic which I can't do in SQL:

if `company_name` in second exists in original, just add the services to original

if it doesnt exist, make a new row in original

Is there an easy way to do this in python, w/ pandas I presume?

Comment: isn't this called an 'outer join' which you _can_ do in SQL? In Pandas you would use `original.merge(seondary, how = 'outer', on='company_name')`. By the way very useful info here: [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: yes, you can do it in SQL too... you'd make an 'outer join' and then add some boolean logic for what to keep, what to drop.  (`case when original.compan_name is null then second.company_name`... etc).